# Сокрытие элементов при открытии клавиатуры

Tags: android, hide, клавиатура

Добрый день!

Можно ли реализовать сокрытие какого-либо элемента разметки, если открывается клавиатура?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать готовое решение, в котором создается отдельный класс SoftKeyboard. Вот исходники на github Soft Keyboard